# Possible to move div tag in DOM?

Tags: jquery

I'm just curious if it's possible to move a div tag to another position in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. To move `<div id="div1" />` inside `<div id="div2" />`, you can do this:

```
$('#div1').appendTo($('#div2'));
```

Any of the `appendTo`, `insertAfter`, `append`, etc. methods will "move" a tag to another location. You can find a list of available jQuery functions [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to change place to this $("#mbSubMenu").append("form.SearchForm"); but it's not working!? What could be wrong? Only the text "form.SearchForm" is placed where I want it, not the form?

Comment: @user790843 - You need to wrap "form.SearchForm" inside a `jQuery()` or `$()`. For example: $("#mbSubMenu").append($("form.SearchForm"));` Make sure that the form as a "SearchForm" class and not ID.

Comment: It's working! I just missed to put a $ sign after append! Thanks!